# Git can't find set buildpack

Tags: ruby, git, heroku, buildpack

So I am learning how to use git with Heroku and I can't seem to git push my set repo.  So I set the buildpack to ruby with Heroku as ruby by doing so..

```
root@slacker:~/ruby# heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby
Buildpack set. Next release on stormy-earth-98069 will use heroku/ruby.
Run git push heroku master to create a new release using this buildpack.
```

Next I try to update my repo using git push and I get an error saying this..

```
root@slacker:~/ruby# git push heroku master
...
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Failed to detect set buildpack https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/ruby.tgz
remote: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
...
```

So I am wondering what could cause git to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question has the answer. According [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure), looks like the directory from where you are running 'git push' doesn't have Gemfile.

Comment: I get the same error but I do have a Gemfile, as well as Gemfile.lock...

Comment: Same here. I have a Gemfile and Gemfile.lock in the directory I'm pushing from. I'm also on master but still getting this error.